# Parsley.js remote validation error

Tags: django, django-forms, parsley.js

I'm building a custom remote validator with Parsley.js (in Django), and I've come to something, but I'm stuck on a pair of issues.

**forms.py**

```
@parsleyfy
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.CharField(label='', required=True, widget = forms.TextInput(
        attrs = {
            'placeholder': 'E-mail',
            'class': 'form-control',
            'id': 'email',
            'data-parsley-remote': '',
            'data-parsley-remote-options': '{ "type": "POST", "dataType": "json" }',
            'data-parsley-remote': '/check_email/',
            'parsley-remote-method': 'POST',
            'data-parsley-remote-validator': 'emailCheck',
            'data-parsley-remote-message': 'The E-mail is already used.'
        }
    ))
```

The **template**

```
<form data-parsley-validate data-parsley-remote id="user_form" method="post" action="/register/" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-parsley-trigger="focusout">

    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ user_form.as_p }}

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info submit" name="submit" value="Register" />

</form>
```

And the **script**

```
Parsley.addAsyncValidator(
  'emailCheck', function (xhr) {
       var email = $('#email').parsley();
       var response=xhr.responseText;
       var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response);
       var jsonResponseText = jsonResponse["response"];

       window.ParsleyUI.removeError(email,'errorUsername');
       if(jsonResponseText == 'This E-mail is ok.')
           return 200;
       if(jsonResponseText == '404')
           window.ParsleyUI.addError(email,'errorUsername',jsonResponseText);
  }, '/email_check/'
);
```

Now, the first problem is that when I write an existing email, there are two messages that show up: the one from the form tag and the other that comes from the Django view (the "jsonResponseText"); whenever I delete the  "jsonResponseText" I get an error: "*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined*".
The second problem is a little bit more annoying: if I write a non-existent E-mail and fill the whole form, when I click on Register, nothing happens. I think the problem is that the server receives a GET request, instead of a POST, but I don't know where it comes from.

I also post **view.py** file, for completeness

```
def register(request):
    registered = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()

            registered = True

            return render(request, 'blog/registered.html')

        else:
            print user_form.errors
    else:
        user_form = CustomUserCreationForm()

    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'user_form': user_form})


@requires_csrf_token
def email_check(request):
    email = request.POST.get('email', False)
    if request.is_ajax():
        if email:
            query_email = CustomUser.objects.filter(email=email)
            if query_email.exists():
                #res = "{0} is already in use.".format(email)
                res = 404
            else:
                res = "This E-mail is ok."
            ajax_vars = {'response': res, 'email': email}
            json_data = json.dumps(ajax_vars)
        else:
            res = "This field is required."
            ajax_vars = {'response': res, 'email': email}
            json_data = json.dumps(ajax_vars)

        return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json')
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `addError`, `removeError`, and return `true` or `false` from your asynchValidator.

Comment: This resolves the problem of the double error message, and that's perfect. Any idea on the other issue? It keeps on sending a GET request, whereas without the remote validator the request is POST.

Comment: Removing "data-parsley-remote" from the template (since I already have it defined in the forms.py file) I don't get the GET request anymore, but the Register button still doesn't work.